# Axios return data not updating a list

Tags: javascript, arrays, axios, get, append

I have this list called reqs_needed. I want to update it based on the information an Axios request returns. This Axios.get request is inside a for loop because I want to get data back a certain number of times. However, my req_needed is not getting pushed to after I try pusing data to it.

My backend works fine as I can successfully send data back to the frontend and it will print correctly. It's just not adding to the list at all.

Here is the code:

```
import "./SuggestedClasses.css";
import Axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import TakenClass from "./types";
import {
  Table,
  Thead,
  Tbody,
  Tr,
  Th,
  Td,
  TableContainer,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";

const SuggestedClasses = () => {
  const mapping: Record<number, string> = {
    0: "CI-H",
    1: "CI-M",
    2: "HASS-S",
    3: "HASS-H",
    4: "HASS-A",
  };

  localStorage.setItem("requirements_satisfied", "[2, 2, 1, 1, 1]");
  const requirements_satisfied = JSON.parse(
    localStorage.getItem("requirements_satisfied") as string
  );

  var reqs_filled = JSON.parse(
    localStorage.getItem("requirements_filled") as string
  );

  var reqs_needed: TakenClass[] = [];

  if (localStorage.getItem("requirements_filled") == null) {
    localStorage.setItem("requirements_filled", "[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]");
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < requirements_satisfied.length; i++) {
    if (reqs_filled[i] < requirements_satisfied[i]) {
      var j = 0;
      while (j < requirements_satisfied[i] - reqs_filled[i]) {
        var hass_attribute = null;
        var communication_requirement = null;
        if (mapping[i][0] === "C") {
          hass_attribute = null;
          communication_requirement = mapping[i];
        } else {
          hass_attribute = mapping[i];
          communication_requirement = null;
        }

        useEffect(() => {
          Axios.get("http://localhost:3000/getClass", {
            data: {
              hass_attribute: hass_attribute,
              communication_requirement: communication_requirement,
            },
          }).then((response) => {
            if (response.data) {
              reqs_needed.push(response.data);
            }
          });
        }, []);
        j++;
      }
    }
  }
  // console.log("reqs_needed", reqs_needed);
  console.log("reqs_needed.length", reqs_needed.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < reqs_needed.length; i++) {
    console.log("here");
    console.log("LOOPING", reqs_needed[i]);
  }

  return (
    <div className="suggestedClassesContainer">
      <h4 className="card-header">Suggested Classes</h4>
      <TableContainer>
        <Table variant="striped" colorScheme="teal">
          <Thead>
            <Tr>
              <Th>Num.</Th>
              <Th>Rating</Th>
            </Tr>
          </Thead>
          <Tbody>
            {reqs_needed.map((req: TakenClass) => {
              if (req != null) {
                return (
                  <Tr>
                    <Td>{req.subject_id}</Td>
                    <Td>{req.rating}</Td>
                  </Tr>
                );
              }
            })}
          </Tbody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SuggestedClasses;
```

The length of reqs_needed is always zero and causes nothing to show up in my frontend table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you're new to React so it's best to learn basics of React first.

But to answer your specific question, it's not updating because a React component does not re-render until its states or props are updated.

Your `reqs_needed` is just a variable inside your component and updating the variable does not re-render the component (meaning, re-draw it) because it's not a state variable.

So, you need to define it as a state variable like this:

```
const [reqsNeeded, setReqsNeeded] = useState([]);
```

And then set it:

```
setReqsNeeded(newData);
```

But loading all data directly inside the function body is not a good idea either because it'll be re-run each time page re-renders, so you need to put it in `useEffect` block like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // load data
}, []);
```

`useEffect` block with `[]` as second param runs only once at the start when your component mounts, so you can avoid re-loading data again and again.

But, you want to pull data in an iteration and push all of them to `reqs_needed`, and setting the state is immutable which means you can't edit the `reqsNeeded` state directly but setting a *new* state.

So, you'd want to store all of your data in a local variable and then call `setReqsNeeded` at the end when the variable is ready.

So, it'll look like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const newReqsNeeded = [];

  // load data
  for (...) {
    // ...
    newReqsNeeded.push(newValue);
  }

  // finally update the state
  setReqsNeeded(newReqsNeeded);
}, []);
```

You should notice I used `camelCase` rather than `lower_case_with_hyphen` because in JS, we usually use the former name pattern. Plus, if we name the final state variable `reqs_needed`, the setter method name will be weirdly `setreqs_needed`, which doesn't look good.

Anyway, as you can see, there are many problems in your code and it's best to look at the [React documentation](https://react.dev/learn) first.

Answer (score 0):

use state and add data inside that
for example -

```
const [reqNeeded, setReqNeeded] = useState([])
```

insert the data inside the set useState -

```
setReqNeeded[response.data]
```

Hope it will help!!